# Extending a div to the bottom of the viewport with scrolling and a header

Tags: html, css

I want an independently scrolling sidebar with a sticky footer to extend to the bottom of the viewport. There is a header that I want to scroll off the screen, so I can't make the content area also independently scroll. The problem I have is that when you scroll the page, the sidebar is no longer tall enough to go to the bottom of the viewport.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MNjMej?editors=1100#0

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="content">
    Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Maecenas faucibus
    mollis interdum. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum.
    Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. Cum sociis natoque
    penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et
    magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient
    montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur
    ridiculus mus. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
    Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec id elit
    non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Donec sed odio dui. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna.
    Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus
    mus. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna.Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Praesent
    commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum.
    Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec sed odio dui. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Donec sed odio dui. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet
    non magna. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur
    ridiculus mus. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna.</div>
  <div class="sidebar">Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Lorem ipsum
    dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec sed odio dui. Praesent commodo
    cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Donec sed odio dui. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl
    consectetur et. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna.Donec
    id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Lorem ipsum dolor
    sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec sed odio dui. Praesent commodo
    cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Donec sed odio dui. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl
    consectetur et. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna.
    Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Lorem ipsum
    dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec sed odio dui. Praesent commodo
    cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Donec sed odio dui. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl
    consectetur et. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna.
    <div class="sidebar-footer">I need this to be visible and at the bottom of the viewport even after scrolling the whole page.</div>
  </div>
</div>

body {
  margin: 0
}

header {
  height: 100px;
  background: lightgray
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  width: 900px;
  margin: auto; 
}

.content {
  flex-basis: 600px;
}

.sidebar {
  flex-basis: 300px;
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  top: 0;
  height: calc(100vh - 100px);
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background: lightblue;
}

.sidebar-footer {
  height: 150px;
  background: pink;
  width: 100%;
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you want the sidebar-footer to be fixed at the bottom of the page and the sidebar-header to be with independent scroll. Your current sidebar height is `calc(100vh - 100px)` which makes the sidebar to be always 100px above the bottom of the page. You need to change that to 100vh, and the sidebar-footer will be fixed at the bottom.

About the independently scrolling sidebar, you can't do that as long as the upper part of the sidebar and `sidebar-footer` are in the same `<div>`. I separated the upper part in new `<div>` with id `#sidebar-header` and changed few styles. Here is a demo of my changes.

https://jsfiddle.net/d0wz1tem/ or

```css
body {
  margin: 0
}

header {
  height: 100px;
  background: lightgray
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  width: 900px;
  margin: auto; 
}

.content {
  flex-basis: 600px;
}

.sidebar {
  flex-basis: 300px;
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  top: 0;
  height:100vh;
}

#sidebar-header{
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background: lightblue;
  height: calc(100vh - 150px);
}

.sidebar-footer {
  height: 150px;
  background: pink;
  width: 100%;
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="content">
    Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Maecenas faucibus
    mollis interdum. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum.
    Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. Cum sociis natoque
    penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et
    magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient
    montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur
    ridiculus mus. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
    Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec id elit
    non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Donec sed odio dui. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna.
    Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus
    mus. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna.Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Praesent
    commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum.
    Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec sed odio dui. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Donec sed odio dui. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet
    non magna. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur
    ridiculus mus. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna.</div>
  <div class="sidebar"><div id="sidebar-header">
  Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Lorem ipsum
    dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec sed odio dui. Praesent commodo
    cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Donec sed odio dui. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl
    consectetur et. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna.Donec
    id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Lorem ipsum dolor
    sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec sed odio dui. Praesent commodo
    cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Donec sed odio dui. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl
    consectetur et. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna.
    Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Lorem ipsum
    dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec sed odio dui. Praesent commodo
    cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Donec sed odio dui. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl
    consectetur et. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna.</div>
    <div class="sidebar-footer">I need this to be visible and at the bottom of the viewport even after scrolling the whole page.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please put the code in the answer, I'm on a mobile and jsfiddle doesn't work. You can [make it runnable here also](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Thanks for the help! I made the sidebar height 100vh - 100px because I have a header I need to account for. The problem is that once you scroll, it creates a gap, as you mentioned. The core of my problem is that I want the sidebar footer to be at the bottom of the sidebar both before and after you scroll.